# Programmatically Get Storage Account Key

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-storage-account

I am building a UWP application. I want to upload and download data to Azure Blob containers belonging to various storage accounts. I do not intend to store the connection strings as they keep rotating.

Is there a way to dynamically get the storage account key?

(I have the container name and Blob URL)

Once I get the account key, I can generate the connection string using:

```
DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<AccountName>;AccountKey=<???>;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net
```

Using Azure.Storage.Blob - V12

Comment: You still need to connect to server,.  You can get the tables names by using GetSchema.  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64724198/azure-function-in-python-get-schema-of-parquet-file?force_isolation=true

Answer (score 0):

**Way-1:** There is one way to get the Storage account key is by using Azure CLI commands as below and I followed [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/account/keys?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-account-keys-list-examples):

```
az storage account keys list -g xx -n yy
```

xx- Name of the resource group
yy- Name of Storage account

[image]

**Way 2:** To get programmatically, Thanks to @Ivan Yang and I followed his [SO-Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65588674) :

> ```
> keys = storage_client.storage_accounts.list_keys(RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME,STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME)
> ```

So the Storage Account key is the value of  `keys.keys[0].value`

**Way 3:** You can also get storage account key by using api and call the below api in c# to get the Key and I followed [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/storage-accounts/list-keys?tabs=HTTP) as below:
POST Req:

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/{accountName}/listKeys?api-version=2021-09-01
```

References :

- [Programmatically get Azure storage account properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44515610/programmatically-get-azure-storage-account-properties)
- [How to rotate an Azure storage account access key from C# code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69882633/how-to-rotate-an-azure-storage-account-access-key-from-c-sharp-code)
- [How to get Azure Storage Account Key (connectionString) using azure .net sdk or fluent API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67818087/how-to-get-azure-storage-account-key-connectionstring-using-azure-net-sdk-or)

Comment: Hi. Thank you. It is very insightful. However, as I mentioned, I am trying to build a UWP application. I cannot store the subscriptionID and resource group name as the app will be on the client machine. It can lead to possible security issues. Can you provide some insights on how I can move further? 

I am authenticating using MSAL. Can I use it somehow?

Comment: You need to give subscription id and resource group to get it using programatically or else you can get directly the keys using Azure portal

Answer (score 0):

I found a Nuget-Package to accomplish the task. I use the "Azure.ResourceManager.Storage" Nuget-Package. Sadly it isn't from Azure.Storage.Blob - V12, but I does the job pretty well.

Btw. to access the keys you need the Role "Storage Account Key Operator Service Role" on the Storage Account.

Here a short example:

```
using Azure.Core;
using Azure.ResourceManager;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Storage;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Storage.Models;
...  

// Create a ArmClient with valid credentials. 
// I use a Service Principal with a certificate
string tenantId = "";
string clientId = "";
string pFXClientCertificatePath = "";

var credentials = new ClientCertificateCredential(tenantId, clientId, new X509Certificate2(pFXClientCertificatePath));
ArmClient client = new ArmClient(credentials);

// the identifier of the StorageAccount (That one you want to access)
// you can find the id in the JSON View of the StorageAccount in the Azure Portal
string resourceId = "/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroup/xx"
StorageAccountResource storageAccount = _armClient.GetStorageAccountResource(new ResourceIdentifier(resourceId));
await foreach (StorageAccountKey key in storageAccount.GetKeysAsync()) {
  return key.Value;
}
```

Here the source of some of the Code. You can also find some more examples there.

Source: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/storage/Azure.ResourceManager.Storage/samples/Sample1_ManagingStorageAccounts.md